# fixing error message regarding target range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Early in the build this code worked perfectly, somewhere over the past 4 month's I think I screwed something up on my target sheet.  I can't understand the error or the adjustments I need to make.  I have tried deleting Columns etc to no avail

Here is the code:

```
function storeDataPlac(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var source = ss.getSheetByName("xArPlace")
var sourceRange = source.getDataRange()
var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues()
Logger.log(sourceValues)
Logger.log("the number of rows of source data = "+sourceValues.length)

var target = ss.getSheetByName("ArPlace")

var targetA1 = target.getDataRange()
Logger.log(targetA1.isBlank())

if (targetA1.isBlank() == true){
// range is blank, so Last Column = 1
var targetLC = 1
Logger.log("Column A is blank")
}
else{
// range is not blank, so last column <>1
var targetLC = target.getLastColumn()+1
Logger.log("the last column on the target sheet = "+targetLC)
}
var targetRange = target.getRange(1,targetLC,sourceValues.length)
Logger.log("The target range = "+targetRange.getA1Notation())
targetRange.setValues(sourceValues)
Logger.log("copies the data")

 }'''
```

here is the error message when I run the function

7:02:19 PM  Error
Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 2 but the range has 1.

7:21:26 PM Info the number of rows of source data = 54 7:21:26 PM Info false 7:21:26 PM Info the last column on the target sheet = 9 7:21:26 PM Info The target range = I1:I54

Col H has Data in it, but Col I is completely empty

Comment: [edit] the question with relevant information. Don't put it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Had another function throwing data into Col B of the source...

My apologies for wasting everybody's time.  You all are such a fabulous resource!

thank you sooo much